# C++ sort on vector using function object

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl, vector

I'm trying to sort a vector v1 using another vector v2. I can't wrap my head around this error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>   what():  vector::_M_range_check
>   Abort trap

while running this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Comp
{
    public:
        Comp(vector<double>& inVec): _V(inVec) {}
        bool operator()(int i, int j) {return (_V.at(i)<_V.at(j));}
    private:
        vector<double> _V;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double x1[] = {90.0, 100.0, 80.0};
    double x2[] = {9.0, 3.0, 1.0};
    vector<double> v1(x1,x1+3);
    vector<double> v2(x2,x2+3);

    sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(), Comp(v2));  // sort v1 according to v2

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<v1.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v1.at(i) << " " << v2.at(i) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`v1` and `v2` are of the same size. Why the `out_of_range` error?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: your `Comp` class should hold a reference to the vector, instead of copying it.

Answer (score 9):

I believe that your problem is in this line:

```
bool operator()(int i, int j) {return (_V.at(i)<_V.at(j));}
```

The problem is that when the `std::sort` algorithm uses a custom callback, it passes in the actual values stored in the `vector` at particular locations, not the *indices* of those locations within the `vector`.  As a result, when you call

```
sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(), Comp(v2));  // sort v1 according to v2
```

The `Comp` comparator you've written will be getting passed as parameters the values stored in the `v1` vector and will then try indexing at those positions into the `v2` vector.  Since the values in `v1` are larger than the size of `v2`, the call to `_V.at(i)` will cause an `out_of_range` exception to be thrown.

If you want to sort the two ranges with respect to one another, you'll need to adopt a different approach.  I'm not aware of a straightforward way of doing this, but I'll let you know if I think of one.

Answer (score 6):

Size of `v1` is just `3`, but you're using each value of `v2` as index of `v1`. And as `v2` has one value `9` which is greater than the size of `v1`, that is what gives `std::out_of_range` error in here:

```
bool operator()(int i, int j) {return (_V.at(i)<_V.at(j));}
```

`std::vector::at` function gives `std::out_of_range` exception of the index passed to it as argument is greater than the size of vector. That is, the index must be less than `vector::size()`.

Answer (score 4):

Like said in other answers, the problem is that the sort algorithm passes the actual values to compare rather than indices.

Here is how you can solve it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<double, double> Zipped; // Represent an element of two lists
                                     // "zipped" together

// Compare the second values of two pairs
bool compareSeconds ( Zipped i, Zipped j )
{
    return i.second < j.second;
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    double x1[] = { 90, 100, 80 };
    double x2[] = { 9, 3, 1 };

    vector<double> v1(x1, x1 + 3);
    vector<double> v2(x2, x2 + 3);

    vector<Zipped> zipped(v1.size()); // This will be the zipped form of v1
                                      // and v2

    for ( int i = 0; i < zipped.size(); ++i )
    {
        zipped[i] = Zipped(v1[i], v2[i]);
    }

    sort(zipped.begin(), zipped.end(), &compareSeconds);

    for ( int i = 0; i < zipped.size(); ++i )
    {
        cout << zipped[i].first << " " << zipped[i].second << endl;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i )
    {
        v1[i] = zipped[i].first;
    }

    // At this point, v1 is sorted according to v2

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, now you're probably aware of the fact, that `i` and `j` are actual values held in `vector` rather than indices. There is a good reason for that: sorting is all about values, not indexes. Note you're passing iterators to `sort` method, so there is no way it can extract index for you. Of course, you could get index relative to first iterator, but there is no reason for doing this.

However, let's be insane for awhile and imagine you would get indices rather than values in your comparator. Assume that your code does what you want and let's think about following scenario:

`v1 = {20,10}; v2 = {2,1}`

I secretly assume you want the following output:

`v1 = {10, 20}`

right? Now imagine I'm a sorting function you're calling and I do following steps:

- `v2[0] < v2[1]` is false, so `swap(&v1[0], &v1[1])`

It's sorted, isn't it? But wait, I'm a crazy sorting function, so I want to make sure it's sorted, so I do the following:

- `v2[0] < v2[1]` is false, `swap(&v1[0], &v1[1])`

And again:

- `v2[0] < v2[1]` is false, `swap(&v1[0], &v1[1])`

and again, again, again...

Can you see a problem? Sorting function has some requirements and for sure you're breaking fundamental one.

I suspect you need completely different container (maybe `std::map` with keys from `vec1` and values from `vec2`) or at least something like `vector< pair<double, double> >`, so you can easily sort by either first or second value. If not, consider creating `vector` with values in range `[0, v2.size())`, sorting it using your comparator (values are equal to indices, so will be all right) and then print correct values from `v1`. This code works fine:

```
vector<size_t> indices;
for(size_t i =0; i < v1.size(); ++i)
{
  indices.push_back(i);
}

// yes, it works using your original comparator
sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), Comp(v2));

for(size_t i =0; i < indices.size(); ++i)
{
    cout << v1.at(indices[i]) << " " << v2.at(indices[i]) << endl;
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving the real reason rather than just saying `std::sort` uses values instead of indices.